In layman's terms, how can an infinite amount of numbers fit within a finite 'distance'?
I am by no means mathematically advanced, so I would appreciate it if you could answer my question in the simplest way you can, so that I understand.

I understand that:



There is an infinite amount of decimal places between 0 and 1.



And



10 is no closer to infinity than 1 is.



But what I don't understand is how can an infinite amount of numbers fit within a finite 'distance' (0 to 1), seeing that every number is an infinite distance from infinity?

The problem here is that we are using words like between, finite, infinite based on their meaning in everyday life and not using their definitions as required in a certain mathematical context.

Try to use the definition of order relations $<, >$ and "between" and confirm that every rational number like $1/2,1/3,\dots$ lies between $0$ and $1 $. There is nothing more to this.

@ParamanandSingh well I guess that is the limiting factor then, seeing as I probably have neither the prior knowledge or time to learn such concepts.

The definitions required here (for statement in my last comment) are available in high school curriculum for students of age 12-13 years. Check out how to compare two rational numbers and just apply the technique here.

@ParamanandSingh well then I should be right… I’d hope!

One way of thinking about it - you can pick the number halfway in between 0 and 1 - namely 1/2. Then pick the number halfway between 0 and 1/2 - i.e. 1/4. Then 1/8, then 1/16, then 1/32. You can do that forever- picking 1/2^n. So there's an infinite list in a finite distance.

10 is closer to infinity than 1. Because it is greater.

Perhaps an analogy will help. Consider a circle. It has infinitely many points, and they are all the same distance from the center.
So there is no particular difficulty in the idea that there can be infinitely many points that all have the same distance from some other point.

Thanks- this actually makes a lot of sense…
